# Multiple Nested IF formula receive Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

I'm trying to write a multiple nested if formula but keep receiving the following error.

Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

```
IF((TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Likely'),TRUE),   
IF((TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Prospecting'),TRUE),
IF((TEXT(StageName) <> 'Donation Likely'||TEXT( StageName ) <> 'Donation 
Prospecting'|| TODAY() < CloseDate,FALSE)
```

Comment: I am trying to say that if the first 2 IF statements evaluates to true then the value of the checkbox should be TRUE. If the last IF statement evaluates to be true then the value of the checkbox should be FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parts. Try this and pay attention to the ??? which is the false part of the last if

```
IF(
   (TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Likely'),
   TRUE,   
     IF(
         (TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Prospecting'),
         TRUE,
            IF(
             TEXT(StageName) <> 'Donation Likely'||TEXT( StageName ) <> 'Donation 
             Prospecting'|| TODAY() < CloseDate,
             FALSE,
             ????
           )
     )
)
```

You are basically doing (from what I gather from your attempt):

```
IF(
   EVAL,
   TRUEPART,
   FALSEPART = IF(EVAL,TRUEPART, FALSEPART = IF(EVAL,TRUEPART,FALSEPART)
)
```

Every IF statement has an Eval, TruePart, and FalsePart. When nesting you can get lost easily.

**Note** I did not evaluate to see if there was a better way of doing what you are trying to do so Optimization is still possible and may be posted as an answer by another SFSE team member :0

Comment: The first 2 if evaluations should be true and the last if should be false

Comment: @VictorMora - no idea what that means. You may be able to take what I have posted and mold it into your needs....

Comment: `IF((TEXT(StageName) <> 'Donation Likely'||TEXT( StageName ) <> 'Donation 
Prospecting'|| TODAY() < CloseDate),FALSE,???)` Parens were missing in the first clause of the if statement to group them together.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think this formula can be simplified?

In first two `IF` `CloseDate` is common only difference is the `StageName` so, we can combine both conditions as:

```
IF(
      (
         TODAY() > CloseDate 
         && (TEXT(StageName)='Donation Likely' || 
             TEXT(StageName) = 'Donation Prospecting')
      ), 
      TRUE, 
      FALSE
)
```

In all other conditions you just want `FALSE` even the `CloseDate > Today()` regardless of stage, formula will evaluate to `false`.

Note: It is little difficult initially but make sure brackets are closed properly.